# Which is the best way to encode batch videos on server side?

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding, server-side

I am making a general question since I am a developer and I have no advance experience  on video elaboration. I have to preparare a web application with the purpose to allow video files upload on our company server and then video elaboration by server, on user command. The purpose of the web application is to allow to the user to make some elaboration on video depending on user action launch from the web app:

1. (server has to ) convert video in different format(mp4, flv...)
2. extact keyframes from video and saves them in jpeg format
3. possibility to extract audio from video
4. automatic control of quality audio & video (black frames,silences detection)
5. change scene detection and keyframe extraction

.....

This what's my bosses wanted from the web based application (with the server support obviously), and I understand only the first 3 points of this list, the rest for me was arabic....

My question is: Which is the best and fastest server side application for this works, that can support multiple batch video conversions, from command line (comand line for php-soap-socket interaction or something else..)?

Is suitable Adobe Media Server for batch video conversion?

Which are adobe products that can be used for this purpose?

Note: I have experience with Indesign Server scripting programing (sending xml with php and soap call...), and I am looking to something similiar for video elaboration.

I will appreciate any answers.

THANKS ALL

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with the open source project [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  You can call the program from the command line and via a series of arguments specify the desired output types, thumbnails, etc.

As an aside, when you start looking around at Video related projects ([MediaShare](http://www.mediasharesuite.com/) for example) you will find they are all using [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for their video processing.

Answer (score 0):

as [Nathan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951592/which-is-the-best-way-to-encode-batch-videos-on-server-side/4951766#4951766), [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is the first choice. Also you can check [MEncoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder)

Just to elaborate:

```
1) (server has to ) convert video in different format(mp4, flv...)
```

both FFMPEG and mencoder do this well

```
2) extact keyframes from video and saves them in jpeg format
```

as I know it's impossible using command-line interface of FFMPEG, not sure about mencoder. However they can save **all** frames as separate images

```
3) possibility to extract audio from video
```

both FFMPEG and mencoder do this well

```
4) automatic control of quality audio & video (black frames,silences detection)
```

you need to code this, using FFMPEG libraries or mencoder

```
5) change scene detection and keyframe extraction
```

it's not clear what your boss imposes here

Comment: thanks, I want to say that I am not searching a free tool, my boss can pay for a better tool for this. THanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot of videos converting in server side using advance Xuggler API libraries.

Xuggler is a free open-source library for Java developers which can be used to uncompress,
    manipulate, and compress recorded or live video in real time. Xuggler uses the very 
    powerful FFmpeg media handling libraries under the hood, essentially playing the role of a
    java wrapper around them. It is the easy way to uncompress, modify, and re-compress any
    media file (or stream) from Java.

WebLinks : 1) http://www.xuggle.com/ -official website
               2) http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-
                  manipulation.html - example